# Replacing iframe source with Javascript - Can I use a loop?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a list of items (districts) on a page, and an iframe pulling in a map on the same page.  When a user clicks on one of the districts, the JavaScript changes the source of the iframe to show a map of the district the user clicked.

My current code simply uses an "onclick" for each district, which then calls a function to change the source of the iframe.

I am wondering if I can simplify this code at all, possibly by using a loop?  If I have 15 more districts to add to the page, will I have to add another "onclick" and another function for each one?  Or is there an easier way that I am missing?

Simplified HTML:

```
<div id="districtlist">
  <a href="#">Allen</a>
  <a href="#">Barren</a>
  <a href="#">Butler</a>
  <!--about 15 more links to follow-->
</div>

<iframe id="maparea" src="http://www.reddit.com"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById("districtlist")

a.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick = Allen;
a.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].onclick = Barren;
a.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].onclick = Butler;
//more lines...


function Allen() {
document.getElementById("maparea").src="http://www.youtube.com";
}

function Barren() {
document.getElementById("maparea").src="http://www.mentalfloss.com";
}

function Butler() {
document.getElementById("maparea").src="http://www.amazon.com";
}

//more functions...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could try this

```
 var elems = document.getElementById("districtlist").querySelectorAll('a');

 [].forEach.call(elems, function(elem) {

    elem.onclick = function() {

     var url = '';

     switch(elem.innerText) {
       case 'Allen':
         url = "http://www.mentalfloss.com";
         break;
       case 'Barren':
         url = "http://www.mentalfloss.com"
         break;
       case 'Butler':
         url = "http://www.amazon.com";
         break;
     }

     document.getElementById("maparea").src=url;

   }

});
```